# How to plot this cake piece like surface in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a cake piece like surface in matlab but I have no idea how to define *z* to make it look like a cake pie. The shape I need is this:
[image]
This is the code I wrote so far:

```
th = linspace(0, pi/3);
r = linspace(0, pi/3);
% z = linspace(0, 10);
[R, TH] = meshgrid(r, th);

x = R.*cos(TH);
y = R.*sin(TH);
z = R;
% z = 10 * ones(size(x));
ss = surf(x, y, z, 'FaceAlpha',0.3);
ss.EdgeAlpha = 0.6;
ss.FaceAlpha = 0.1;
```

Comment: The built in `pie3` is not what you want? https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pie3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will look similar to that shape, but not exactly, I mean the shape will be rough:

```
z = rand(size(x));
```

another option with smoother surface:

```
z = zeros(size(x));
[m,n]=size(x);
for i=1 : n
    for j=1 : m
        if(mod(i+j,2)==0)
            z(i,j) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```